# Error 2002 because of PCL

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have created my own Portable Class Library and added it to an already existing Windows Universal app. The Windows app was updated without a hitch, but the Windows Phone app gives error 2002. After a bit of testing I dediced that the problem is the PCL. It only happens in Release build, in Debug build the problem does not occur. 
The MDILXapCompileLog.Txt says the following about the matter:

CrossGen failed
Error processing assembly PCLPATH.dll
Raw error code: 2148734277

The error 2002 means: "The named resource or the named resource's language was not found in the .PRI file.". If this is the issue, how do I fix it?

After a bit of googling I have found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/411d9560-da63-4eb4-beee-6f376e20d6c3/windows-phone-81-universal-app-submission-of-a-non-localized-application-error-code-2002?forum=wpdevelop).

Could this be the problem? That one of the classes is too big, or something?

Does anyone have a suggestion for fixing this issue?

I've already tried a lot of things. After spending 2 days on this issue, I've decided that it's time to ask for help.

Comment: The raw error is 0x80131545, COR_E_MAXMETHODSIZE, "A method in this assembly is greater than the maximum allowed method size".  Hmm, that ought to be a humdinger of a method, not hard to find back :)

Comment: I tried googling that error code. Couldn't find it. Thanks! I'll have something to do tomorrow :D

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if a C# class is too big.

Projects with this problem are able to run on the Windows Phone Emulator, but fail when trying to deploy on a real device.

In my case the issue was caused by [LocaleData.cs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aidanbebbington/libphonenumber-csharp/b81de60081e3817792305f5c5252a3b48665028a/csharp/PhoneNumbers/LocaleData.cs) from the [libphonenumber-csharp](https://github.com/aidanbebbington/libphonenumber-csharp) project. After reducing the size of this file, the project was able to run on a device.